# SQL window function is grouped, but still get "must be an aggregate expression or appear in GROUP BY clause"

Tags: sql, presto, trino

I have a SQL (presto) query, let's say it's this:

```sql
select
      id
    , product_name
    , product_type
    , sum(sales) as total_sales
    , sum(sales) over (partition by type) as sales_by_type

from some_table

group by 1,2,3
```

When I run this, I get an error telling me that the window function needs to appear in the `GROUP BY` clause. Is the best solution to break this out with a subquery? Or is there some syntax changes I need to make for this to work?

Comment: Your grouping by the first three fields and then computing an aggregation and a window function. The window function is not a grouping operation, so that’s why it fails. What are you trying to achieve. If you spell that out it would make it easier to suggest a solution

Comment: Thanks @MartinTraverso -- I guess my question is whether or not it's possible to have an aggregation and a window function in the same select statement.

Comment: You can, but it depends on what you're trying to do. Logically, aggregations/group-by get evaluated first and then the window functions are applied on the result. For instance, you can have queries with the following shape: `SELECT first_value(sum(c)) OVER (PARTITION BY b) FROM t GROUP BY a, b`, which is equivalent to `SELECT first_value(x) OVER (PARTITION BY b) FROM (SELECT a, b, sum(c) AS x FROM t GROUP BY a, b)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is something like below

```
select
      id
    , product_name
    , product_type
    , sum(sales) over () as total_sales
    , sum(sales) over (partition by type) as sales_by_type
    from some_table
```

or

```
select
      id
    , product_name
    , product_type
    , sum(sales) over (partition by (select 1)) as total_sales
    , sum(sales) over (partition by type) as sales_by_type
    from some_table
```

Both of these works in sql server. Not sure what/if it will work for presto though.

I have seen below variation as well.

```
over (partition by null)
```

Comment: `OVER ()` is the idiomatic way to do it in Presto / Trino.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the total sales for the type, then you need to nest the `sum()`s:

```
select id, product_name, product_type,
       sum(sales) as total_sales,
       sum(sum(sales)) over (partition by type) as sales_by_type
from some_table
group by 1,2,3;
```

If you also want the total of all sales, then:

```
select id, product_name, product_type,
       sum(sales) as total_sales,
       sum(sum(sales)) over (partition by type) as sales_by_type,
       sum(sum(sales)) over () as total_total_sales
from some_table
group by 1,2,3;
```